# Kivy: AttributeError: 'CreateButton' object has no attribute '_disabled_count'

Tags: python, button, kivy

I am trying to create a dashboard of buttons on the Raspberry Pi touchscreen as a home hobby and I want to create some buttons that you press and release, some that latch on and off and some that have multiple states.

I want to change the state of a button when it is pressed. So I can detect that the button is pressed via the CreateButton class, but I want to pass the button state information in at **init**. When I do so, I get

*AttributeError: 'CreateButton' object has no attribute '_disabled_count'*

If I remove the **init** in CreateButton the code runs, which I don't understand. Can you suggest where I'm going wrong?

Many thanks

**Main.py**

```
import pickle
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.image import AsyncImage
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from typing import List

# Define the data structure of a button state
class StateDefinition(object):
    def __init__(self, Label, Image, Colour, Action):
        self.Label = Label
        self.Image = Image
        self.Colour = Colour
        self.Action = Action

# Define the data structure of a button
class ButtonDefinition(object):
    def __init__(self, buttonname: str, currentstate: int, buttonstates: List[StateDefinition]):
        self.currentstate = currentstate
        self.buttonname = buttonname
        self.buttonstates = buttonstates

# Define the data structure of a dashboard - a collection of related buttons
class DashboardDefinition(object):
    def __init__(self, dashboardname: str, dashboardbuttons: List[ButtonDefinition]):
        self.dashboardname = dashboardname
        self.dashboardbuttons = dashboardbuttons

# This class creates the kivy button and binds it to the action
class CreateButton(Button):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        print("Got Here")

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        if self.collide_point(*touch.pos):
            if touch.button == "right":
                print(self.id, "right mouse clicked")
            elif touch.button == "left":
                print(self.id, "left mouse clicked")
            else:
                print(self.id)
            return True
        return super(CreateButton, self).on_touch_down(touch)

## This is the class that builds the Carousel of buttons
class BuildLayout(GridLayout):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(BuildLayout, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.build_dashboard()

    def build_dashboard(self):

        # Define all the test data
        state1 = StateDefinition(Label = 'State 1', Image = 'Image1.png', Colour = '#FF0000', Action = 'A')
        state2 = StateDefinition(Label = 'State 2', Image = 'Image2.png', Colour = '#00FF00', Action = 'B')
        state3 = StateDefinition(Label = 'State 3', Image = 'Image3.png', Colour = '#0000FF', Action = 'C')
        button1 = ButtonDefinition(buttonname = "Button 1", currentstate = 0, buttonstates = [state1])
        button2 = ButtonDefinition(buttonname = 'Button 2', currentstate = 0, buttonstates = [state2, state1])
        button3 = ButtonDefinition(buttonname = 'Button 3', currentstate = 0, buttonstates = [state3, state2, state1])
        dashboard1 = DashboardDefinition(dashboardname = "Test Dashboard", dashboardbuttons = [button1, button2, button3])

        for buttonID in range(0, len(dashboard1.dashboardbuttons)):
            buttonwidget = CreateButton(id = str(buttonID))
            buttonwidget.text = dashboard1.dashboardbuttons[buttonID].buttonname + "\nButton State: " + \
                                str(dashboard1.dashboardbuttons[buttonID].currentstate)
            self.add_widget(buttonwidget)

# This is tha main class that sets up the app
class LayoutApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return BuildLayout()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    LayoutApp().run()
```

**Layout.kv**

```
#:kivy 1.11.0

<CreateButton>:
    font_size: 18
    on_touch_down: self.on_touch_down

<BuildLayout>:
    rows: 3
    cols: 3
    row_force_default: True
    row_default_height: 150
    col_force_default: True
    col_default_width: 150
    padding: [10]
    spacing: [10]
```

Answer (score 2):

When you override the `__init__` method for Kivy elements, it won't do the inherited `__init__` method unless you manually tell it to. If you don't do that, it won't get set up properly with all the properties Kivy expects (like `_disabled_count`).

I expect this will work if you just add `super().__init__(**kwargs)` (or `super(<classname>, self).__init__(**kwargs)` for Python 2 compatibility) as the first line of your new `__init__` methods, like you did in `BuildLayout`. It's easy to forget!